# I am trying to copy only files which are latest version in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to copy only files which are latest  version in Bash.

For example in my below script i am coping all the files but now i need to copy the latest version(the latest version will be given as the last param in the filename)

**Example of my file name**

```
AAA_BBB_CCC_1
AAA_BBB_CCC_2 (i need to copy this file instead the above one because iot has _2 which means                           it is the latest version)
BBB_CCC_DDD_1
BBB_CCC_DDD_2(i need to copy this file)
```

So the i need to check for the matching file name then the extendent version of it and get the latest version

**My basic script which will copy all the files:-**

```
#!/bin/bash 

cp $S/*  $W/;

echo "DONE"
```

Comment: You might want to use a proper version control tool, instead of specially constructed file names, to track version information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--update` (or `-u`) flag:

> copy  only  when  the  SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing

```
cp --update $S/*  $W/;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick responce, the destination file does not have anything(i am removeing for all the files from detination to once they move to some other X folder - that is my busines logic)                          I have all the version in S folder and i need to get the latest one